# jdk7: sun.font.fontManager replacement/how to get filename information from fontname

Tags: java, fonts, java-7, jdk-internal-api

**Using Oracle(Sun) JDK6 and trying to move to Oracle JDK7**

I am using `sun.awt.GraphicsEnvironment` to find all system fonts in order to use them to change pdf font used in my pdf file. Here is the exact code I am using:

```
GraphicsEnvironment gEnv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

// get all system fonts
final Font[] fonts = gEnv.getAllFonts();
```

After that I will need to get the exact font file path on the system, so I use:

```
FontManager.getFontPath(true) + "/" +
               FontManager.getFileNameForFontName(font_name);
```

The problem now is that `sun.font.FontManager` is no longer a class and has been converted to an interface. I searched online and came up with some solutions that I am not satisfied with and I am looking for other ideas to help solve my problem.

**The solutions that I found:**

1. Deploy my project on Java 6 instead of Java 7 (Not recommend as I use some new features in Java 7).
2. I found the code of the FontManager class online, but using it will require including a lot of other classes/interfaces and the process seems dummy and time consuming. Also I am not if I am allowed to use that code as it's proprietary of Sun company.

**What I need is:** **A way to find the exact font file path on the system**. All ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Marcel Stör's answer about using Win32FontManager helped to solve the problem in Windows only. I suspect it wouldn't work on Linux or Mac OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not saying which JDK you use (Oracle, OpenJDK, ..). Possibly you have

```
FontManagerFactory.getInstance()
```

available. Or the inteface implementation `Win32FontManager` (if you're on Windows)?

Comment: The real question is 'how to get the A way to find the exact font file path on the system'

Comment: @Jayan, yes I know that. Was requested for Java >10 years ago: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4752644

Comment: @Jayan, I got the bounty, thanks. What was the solution in your particular case?

Comment: I used reflection and accessed the variable that holds the  file path.  I will put that code here later.

Comment: @Jayan: Can you please put the code here? I have the same problem now

Comment: using Win32FontManager helped to solve the problem, but it introduced another issue as it's platform dependent as I guess. Do you have any idea about a platform independent solution.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

This code works on Windows 10 and IBM Java 8

```
sun.font.SunFontManager.getInstance().getPlatformFontPath(true)
```

But on macOS 11 and AdoptOpenJDK 8/11 an empty string is returned.