# Getting font file from SWT font for PDFBox

Tags: java, swt, pdfbox

I'm trying to export a Draw2D Figure to a PDF file, using PDFBox.

The software will be used on both Windows and Mac OS X.

From the Figure I can get SWT font objects (`org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font`). Available fonts are obtained from the JFace FontRegistry.

To embed a font in the PDF, I can embed a TrueType font with `PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF( PDDocument doc, File file )` or variants.

Given an SWT font object or a font name, how can I get the file path to the font file?

**EDIT:**

There's a similar question here: [Get font file as a File object or get its path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019249/get-font-file-as-a-file-object-or-get-its-path). However, the accepted answer is fragile and platform-specific. It relied on an [internal API that changed between Java 6 and Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684342/jdk7-sun-font-fontmanager-replacement-how-to-get-filename-information-from-font). This question seeks a solution that is cross-platform and does not couple to internal implementation details.

Comment: I've been wrestling with the same kind of problem--my hack around it was to index the names, paths, and some other attributes of TTF files in common directories. I used [sfntly](http://code.google.com/p/sfntly/) to do that. It's very very very very hackish but it worked for what I needed.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing the idea. I had thought of doing something similar, but was concerned that any set of well-known common font directories that I specify might be incomplete, and about whether there would be a startup lag that increased with the number of fonts on the user's system.